# proof by using induction

Tags: induction

I'm trying to prove the following by induction but I'm stuck.

$x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2, x_n=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})$.

Show that:
$x_n-x_{n+1} = \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n-1}}$

I proved the basis step, but I'm stuck in the inductive step.
I tried going from L.H.S and take as $x_{n+2}$ as common divisor and had $(x_{n-1} - 1)$. I didn't know where to go from there..

Comment: I've just edited with what I believed to be what you meant to write, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DavidPeterson  When editing, please do so thoroughly.

Comment: @Bernard  You too.

Comment: I'm sorry ,I only edit what I understand. I can see there's a problem in the last sentence, but I don't know what it should really be.

Comment: @amWhy And perhaps you? Check out your subscripts in the last paragraph (which I had fixed).

Comment: in the question how do I make 2^n-1 (n-1 is the power)

Comment: It seems like it should be $x_n-x_{n+1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n-1}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note you have, using the recurrence relation,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x_{n+1} - x_{n+2} & = x_{n+1} - \frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1} + x_{n}) \\
& = x_{n+1} - \frac{x_{n+1}}{2} - \frac{x_{n}}{2} \\
& = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1} - x_{n}) \\
& = -\frac{1}{2}(x_{n} - x_{n+1})
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Comment: I tried doing that. i've substituted $x_n$ value but I'm not sure what to cancel with $x_{n+1}$  I feel so dumb because it seems so simple. thanks in advance.

Comment: @raydiiii I'm not sure what you mean by "not sure what to cancel with $x_{n+1}$". Note in my ($1$) equation, if you substitute for $x_n - x_{n+1}$ what you have by the assumption in the inductive step, i.e., that $x_n - x_{n+1} = \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n-1}}$, you'll get that $x_{n+1} - x_{n+2} = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n-1}}\right) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n}} = \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{2^{(n+1)-1}}$. Do you see this is in the same form as your assumption, but with $n$ replaced with $n + 1$?

Comment: omg!!! yeah I get it now!! I really don't know whats wrong with me lol. thanks a lot.

Comment: done! hope you have a nice day.